# How long does conception take?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction

I know that conception is a multi-step process. A sperm fuses with an egg. Its contents diffuse into the cytoplasm. 
Dad's DNA is transported to the nucleus. Proteins are gradually made from Dad's DNA. Do we know how long that process takes?

I'm most curious about conception in humans, but information about other species is welcome too.

EDIT:  The time I'm interested in is between the fusing of sperm and egg, and the first transcription of the newly incorporated paternal DNA within the zygote's nucleus. However, if conception is better defined by different events, feel free to correct me. I'm far from a specialist in the subject.

Comment: Can you define exactly which timespan you're interested in? Ejaculation to DNA entering nucleus? Sperm contacting egg to DNA nuclear entry? Some point until the first cell division? Please [edit] your question to clarify it, otherwise it is rather unclear.

Comment: Done. I figured there might be a research project somewhere that dealt with early embryonic growth, so I guess I was pretty general.

Comment: There is [research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23856356) showing that spermatozoa contain a number of RNA species, including mRNA, so theoretically translation could begin almost immediately. The Wikipedia articles on [human fertilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_fertilization) and [fertilization in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fertilisation) contain lots of other information, if you haven't read them already. Unfortunately, there's nothing in them about timing that I could find. I'm sure it's out there, though.